# Getting a cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED when I click on a video link on my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on a link page I get a redirect to this page: 
https://www.youtube.com/embed/undefined I am using fancybox as well.

This is the full error in the console:

```
GET chrome-extension://fjhoaacokmgbjemoflkofnenfaiekifl/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
Mj @ www-embed-player.js:602
Lj @ www-embed-player.js:599
(anonymous function) @ www-embed-player.js:599
Mj.c.onerror @ www-embed-player.js:601
```

From what I saw from googling the issue this is an error from google itself? Anyway, here is function that links to the actual video:

```
function getOutput(item) {
  var videoId = item.id.videoID;
  var title = item.snippet.title;
  var description = item.snippet.description;
  var thumb = item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url;
  var channelTitle = item.snippet.channelTitle;
  var videoDate = item.snippet.publishedAt;

  var output = '<li>' +
  '<div class="list-left">' +
  '<img src="'+thumb+'">' +
  '</div>' +
  '<div class="list-right">' +
  '<h3><a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+videoId+'">'+title+'</a></h3>' +
  '<small>By <span class="cTitle">'+channelTitle+'</span> on '+videoDate+'</small>' +
  '<p>'+description+'</p>' +
  '</div>' +
  '</li>' +
  '<div class="clearfix"></div>' +
  '';

  return output;

}
```

Would appreciate any direction of how to get the video to play!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear, from the error message, that the variable `videoId` is undefined. perhaps what you've passed into the function is not declared?

From the line : `href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+videoId+'"`

Comment: This is the response from the youtube api: http://prntscr.com/9fqsre and I use function(data) {         $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
          var output = getOutput(item);

          $('#results').append(output);
        });

Comment: Thanks! found the error, wrote item.id.videoID instead of item.id.videoId